# How to run a C++ scratch file in Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio-3.0

I can create a C++ scratch file in Android Studio.
Is it possible to run it?

I used this as an example scratch:

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Trt\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not impossible (I'm doing it to run C++ tests), but it requires some custom plumbing in Gradle, that by default supports Android apps, not standalone C++ x86 apps.

Since Android runtime is JVM, NDK is used to create libraries callable via JNI and the build systems experience is optimized for that.

If you want to kickstart NDK project, I advice you to check out this Google sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni

If you want to run standalone C++ binaries, I advice you to check **CLion** or write your app/lib as a custom CMake project not relying on NDK at all and then create a custom Gradle task to build it.

You probably (I can only guess) want to check hello-jni sample and CLion first.

Comment: Thanks, but I was rather hoping that it would work out of the box (with some easy tweaks).

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can run using terminal of android studio.
create a shell script file. Add this command <g++ testfile.cpp -o testfile && testfile> in that file and save edit the configuration by add the project path.
And click the run button it will run in cmd of android studio.
Note: Before that u need to set up the c++ environment(Ex: mingw and other toold need to install)
[screenshot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFstM.png)